# How to generate DEBIAN/md5sums file in this file structure?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, md5sum

I have the following file structure to build a Debian package, which doesn't contain any binary file (compiling task):

```
source/
source/DEBIAN
source/etc
source/usr
build.sh
```

The content of `build.sh` file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
md5sum `find . -type f | awk 'source/.\// { print substr($0, 3) }'` > DEBIAN/md5sums
dpkg-deb -b source <package-name_version>.deb
```

The problem is that the md5sum command here considers also `DEBIAN/` files when making `DEBIAN/md5sums` file. I want to except `DEBIAN/` files from the md5sum process.

Answer (score 2):

Your Awk script contains a syntax error and probably some sort of logic error as well.  I guess you mean something like

```
md5sum $(find ./source/ -type f |
  awk '!/^\.\/source\/DEBIAN/ { print substr($0, 3) }') > DEBIAN/md5sums
```

Equivalently, you could exclude `source/DEBIAN` from the `find` command line; but since you apparently want to postprocess the output with Awk anyway, factoring the exclusion into the Awk script makes sense.

The upgrade from `` `backticks` `` to `$(dollar-paren)` command substitution is not strictly necessary, but nevertheless probably a good idea.

Apparently, this code was copy/pasted from a script which uses `substr` to remove the leading `./` from the output from `find`.  If (as indicated in comments) you wish to remove more, the script has to be refactored, because you cannot (easily) feed relative paths to `md5sum` which are not relative to the current directory.  But moving more code to `find` and trimming the output with a simpler Awk script works fine:

```
find ./source -path '*/DEBIAN' -prune -o -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | 
awk '{ print $1 "  " substr($2, 10) }'
```

Comment: It works fine, the only problem is that the word `source/` appears in each line in `DEBIAN/md5sums` file.

Comment: I assumed the `substr` was to get rid of just the `./` from the beginning of each line.  Use a bigger index to chop off more -- `substr($0, 10)` should work fine here.

Comment: You mean replacing `substr($0, 3)` with `substr($0, 10)`? It doesn't work; it generates an empty `DEBIAN/md5sums` file.

Comment: `find...` command generates a perfect result to stdout, but when I put this command in `md5sum $()` command, it generates an empty `DEBIAN/md5sums` file.

Comment: Like the demo link in my previous comment illustrates, it works for me with what I have been able to guess about your requirements; but I have been second-guessing them a lot. There's a "fork" link in IdeOne where you can play with the script -- if you can make it set up a test environment more similar to yours (I just have simple `mkdir` and `touch` commands to set up a crude `source` tree) maybe we can see what's wrong. But you really should work on expressing your requirements properly.

Answer (score 2):

find could ignores files specifying a pattern inside their path:

```
find . -type f -not -path "*DEBIAN*"
```

Comment: To be more complete, probly the cleanest way to do this is like so (from within your package directory): `md5sum $(find * -type f -not -path 'DEBIAN/*') > DEBIAN/md5sums`

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering the results of find through e.g. `grep -v` to exclude:

```
find . -type f | grep -v '^./source/DEBIAN/' | ...
```

Or you can probably do the filtering in awk as well...

Comment: Yes. This is also described here: https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-create-a-debian-deb-package/